# Not receiving mail from php mail() function

Tags: php, html

I'm using mail() to send email to users when they sign up but the emails are not arriving.

```
$to = $email;
$subject = 'DC Account Verification';
$message = 'messagecontent';
$headers = 'From: email@test.com' . '\r\n';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I don't get an error. I've tried echoing out the variables to make sure they're all correct and they are. I'm using x10hosting, which I've used before, and this same function worked then. It's just not working now.

Help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Try using double-quotes instead of single. Sometimes, that's the fault. Also, some (if free) hosting companies will disable outgoing mail in PHP and still not show errors.

Comment: I would make sure to check the php.ini file to make sure your host is running a SMTP server that can relay your messages. If you can't check it, I'd ask. Also, the third line needs a semi-colon at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are using single quotes, that's because when you use single quotes php does not interprets the escaping characters "\r\n". So just change them to double quotes.

More information here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Double quotes did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is from the unnecessary `\r\n` after the FROM line.

Try this:

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "DC Account Verification";
$message = "messagecontent";
$headers = "From: email@test.com";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Also, I recommend double-quotes for this.

Comment: Email still did not send. I'm checking the php.ini file although the hoster says that it allows SMTP.